# iframes div takes extra spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add elements using display: inline-block, everything works correct except for the div with iframes. It's always has an extra margin at the bottom but I cannot file a style to override.

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z24pjwk/). What's wrong in there?

My iframe div:

```
.map__section {
  width: 40%;
  height: 410px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFD100;
}

/*
.container-header-back {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #FFD100;
} */

.container__header {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.header__h1 {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Extrabold";
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.header__quote__text {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Light";
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.header__quote__text:after {
  content: close-quote;
}

.header__quote__text:before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.header__quote__footer {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navigation_link {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.navigation_link:hover {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #4b4f54;
}

.container__about {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container__about {
  background-color: white;
}

.container__tell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container__tell {
  background-color: white;
}

.main__section__h2 {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
}

.main__section__text {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form__field {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main__section__h2__form {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
}

.container__form {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.submit__form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFB500;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.submit__form:hover {
  background-color: #FAE053;
}

.main {
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form__section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.map__section {
  width: 40%;
  height: 410px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
}

.map__section iframe {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">

  <section class="container__about">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2">What you are doing here</h2>
    <p class="main__section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
      exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
  </section>

  <section class="container__tell">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2">What I can tell you</h2>
    <p class="main__section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
      exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
  </section>


  <section class="form__section">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2__form">How you can find me</h2>
    <div class="container__form">
      <form action="/" method="">

        <input class ="form__field" type="text" id="fname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name...">

        <input class ="form__field" type="text" id="lname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

        <input class ="form__field" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address..">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit__form">
      </form>
      <div class="div__img">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-facebook-48.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-instagram-48.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-sent-filled-50.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="map__section">

    <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=1%20Grafton%20Street%2C%20Dublin%2C%20Ireland+(My%20Business%20Name)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

  </section>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you setup all you card in `display: inline-block`. So: Act as **text** but allow to setup width and height. 
So you vertical alignment wasn't on top but on baseline.

This is an example using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #FFD100;
}

/*
.container-header-back {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #FFD100;
} */

.container__header {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.header__h1 {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Extrabold";
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.header__quote__text {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Light";
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.header__quote__text:after {
  content: close-quote;
}

.header__quote__text:before {
  content: open-quote;
}

.header__quote__footer {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.navigation {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navigation_link {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.navigation_link:hover {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #4b4f54;
}

.container__about {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container__about {
  background-color: white;
}

.container__tell {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.container__tell {
  background-color: white;
}

.main__section__h2 {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
}

.main__section__text {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.form__field {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Regular";
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main__section__h2__form {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Semibold";
  text-align: center;
}

.container__form {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.submit__form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFB500;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.submit__form:hover {
  background-color: #FAE053;
}

.main {
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form__section {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.map__section {
  width: 40%;
  height: 410px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: block;
  margin: 1em;
}

.map__section iframe {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">

  <section class="container__about">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2">What you are doing here</h2>
    <p class="main__section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
      exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
  </section>

  <section class="container__tell">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2">What I can tell you</h2>
    <p class="main__section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
      exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>
  </section>


  <section class="form__section">
    <h2 class="main__section__h2__form">How you can find me</h2>
    <div class="container__form">
      <form action="/" method="">

        <input class ="form__field" type="text" id="fname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name...">

        <input class ="form__field" type="text" id="lname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

        <input class ="form__field" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address..">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit__form">
      </form>
      <div class="div__img">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-facebook-48.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-instagram-48.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/icons8-sent-filled-50.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="map__section">

    <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=1%20Grafton%20Street%2C%20Dublin%2C%20Ireland+(My%20Business%20Name)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed"></iframe>

  </section>

</main>
```